# Como remover essa caixa preta quando teclo aspas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, osx

Seguinte, eu estou aprendendo um pouco de VBA e tem um negócio que tá me incomodando demais. Toda vez que eu inicio alguma linha com ' ou ", o VBA abre essa caixa preta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nela eu até consigo escrever o resto do código, mas pra sair dela eu preciso apertar enter duas vezes. Aí eu queria que não tivesse essa caixa, que eu conseguisse escrever "direto" no código.
Tem como tirar essa "feature"?

Eu uso o excel no mac.

Comment: Evite o uso de meta tag no título. As meta tags no título devem ser de uso exclusivo do sistema para informar aos usuários o estado da pergunta. Veja [Devemos remover meta tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/808/devemos-remover-meta-tags)

Comment: @capanema, eu nunca vi essa linha preta. Talvez seja alguma configuração (mas se for o caso, não foi padrão em nenhum dos meus Offices - que sempre foram do Windows).

Comment: @CésarRodriguez pois é! pior que eu não lembro de ter feito alguma alteração pra que aparecesse isso, acho que já veio padrão pro mac. E também não consigo achar uma solução pesquisando em português/inglês.

Answer (score -1):

Veja se o problema está nas configurações de formatação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]